# How to do basic auth with HAProxy while doing other ACL?

Tags: haproxy, http-basic-authentication

I am running HAProxy in front of apache servers and I want to implement basic authentication for some domains.

The manual states that this should do the trick:

```
userlist admins
user myusername insecure-password mypassword

frontend restricted_cluster
   acl auth_tintoretto http_auth(admins)
   http-request auth realm ShareaholicRestricted
```

However, I have some other ACL and under one frontend there are several domains:

```
 frontend http-in

    # Define hosts
    acl stag_static hdr(host) -i staging.static.domain.com
    acl prod_static hdr(host) -i prod2.static.domain.com

    ## figure out which one to use
    use_backend apache-node1 if stag_static
    use_backend nginx-cluster if prod_static
```

How do I combine those commands in order to only restrict access to stag_static?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested, but try putting the `http-request auth realm blah` line in your backend configuration.  It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Predicate the `http-request auth` on the ACL matching the site that you want to auth:

```
frontend http-in
  acl stag_static hdr(host) -i staging.static.example.com
  acl prod_static hdr(host) -i prod2.static.examplecom

  http-request auth realm "The No Homers Club" if stag_static

  use_backend apache-node1 if stag_static
  use_backend nginx-cluster if prod_static
```